# REST returns xml

Tags: jquery, rest, jquery-events, ajaxform

I have a REST Web service which returns a JAXB object. I have given a Mediatype as JSON to the method. I am using ajaxForm plugin to send some data to this WebService.

The problem is that inspite of giving JSON as mediatype in the webservice and also giving it in the client Javascript as the dataType, I am still getting only xmlDocument as the returned object.

This is the webservice signature. I am using Glassfish 3.1 and all the functionality gets executed properly (seen messages in the server.log).

```
@Path("GetJson")
public class GetJson
{
    private static  Logger   logger = Logger.getLogger("GetJson");
    @POST
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Exceldatalist getJson(@Context HttpServletRequest request)
{
```

This is the client code. Form is :

```
<form id="form3" action="http://comp1:8080/RestWSGS/jersey/GetJson" style="display:none"
         enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
         <input id ="username" name="username" type="hidden" />
         <input id ="purpose" name="purpose" type="hidden" value="new"  /> 
        <input id ="filename" name="filename" type="hidden" />
        <input id ="password" name="password" type="hidden"  value="abc"/>
        <input id ="company" name="company" type="hidden" value="Third"/>
        <input id ="ignoreSheet" name="ignoreSheet" type="hidden" />
        <input type="submit"  style="display:none" />
</form>
```

ajaxForm call is :

```
$('#form3').ajaxForm({
     url: 'http://comp1:8080/RestWSGS/jersey/GetJson', 
        async: false,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json', 
        contentType: "multipart/form-data",
        processData: false,
        success: function(data)
         {
          myData = data;
          alert('success '+myData);
          
         }
});
```

Apart of this there is only a call for `submit()` for the form.

I fail to understand what I am doing wrong. I am stuck here for some time now...
Please help me unravel this!

Comment: Is the REST web service hosted by you or it is hosted by some other agencies or client?

Comment: So you have to change the server response to be sent as the JSON object instead of sending it as JAX (i.e) XML object. Your client side code is correct, but the REST server has to send the response in JSON. JAX sends only in XML format. You have manually handle it to send it as JSON.

Comment: i have called the webservice from another client with the same settings and using glassfish 3.0 instead of 3.1 and jersey uses jackson to convert it automatically to json given the dataType as 'json'

Comment: So there might some configuration problem with Glassfish 3.1

Comment: any pointers as to where should i look???

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to resolve this.

I removed all jersey and jackson jars from my project.

deleted all jersey and jackson jars from glassfish installation directory/modules. Got all the latest jars from jersey and put them there.

Then deleted the osgi-cache from glassfish and restarted the server. This resolved my problem though what exactly changed I cannot say!!